# Searching a folder directory for a file and retrieving file path's in a web application

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, web-applications

Note: I have never used PHP in my life.

I have come to the point in my mobile web application that I need to find out of a file exists in a structure like:

```
-Folder
    -SubFolder
        -file.html
    -SubFolder
        -file.html
    ...
-Folder
    -Subfolder
        -file.html
...
```

I care to see if this html file exists for a certain subfolder so that if it does I can display its html contents.

I have written the rest of my mobile web application using solely html and javascript but from what I've read it seems this is not doable with javascript alone. ( :( )

So I have a few questions as I sit here looking up everything I need to implement this in PHP (since this is the most common thing I am seeing when looking up how to do this).

1. Currently all I have been using in this application (simple application) is

   ```
   index.html
   style.css
   code.js
   any image files I use or text files I read from using javascript
   ```

Would the PHP code go in the HTML file? Currently the way I have it set up is my index.html file calls a initialization() function that is called when the page loads, and the rest of the application is run from the code.js file that just updates the  elements of the html file. How can I add this PHP to the HTML file to be run when I need it to? Can PHP go into a javascript file? Pretty much after a bunch of logic in the JS file I get to a point where I decide if I need to or not need to search the file structure for a file.

So now on the actual code on how to do it in PHP, from what I've found..

```
 <?php
 $filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
     echo "The file $filename exists";
 } else {
     echo "The file $filename does not exist";
 }
 ?>
```

I pulled that from php.net. One thing about my folder structure is I will know the paths of the files ahead of time. So I feel like it may be easy to follow that format and see if file_exists($filename). My question is instead of echoing a string like in the example can I echo the actual path to the html file? Where does "echo" return the value?

Again this is all new to me, and if this is doable in any easier way (jquery?) I would love to know. My main concern is where to put this php code or how to call it when I want to and have it return something that I can use in my javascript code.

Thanks

Comment: If by what you're asking is doable using an `.html` extension, no. It needs to have the `.php` extension, unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` as PHP.

Comment: What you might be looking for is the `glob()` function ([Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)). It can search a dir for a given pattern, returning files that match the pattern.